# ¿Cómo ordenar alfabéticamente palabras con acentos en un array (arreglo)?

Tags: php, array

Estoy tratando de ordenar alfabéticamente una variable de tipo array de la siguiente forma:

**Código**

```php
$palabras = array(
    'así',
    'alfabeto',
    'alfabético',
    'año',
);

sort($palabras);
var_export($palabras);
```

**Resultado**

```php
array (
  0 => 'alfabeto',
  1 => 'alfabético',
  2 => 'así',
  3 => 'año',
)
```

Pero como se ve, no funciona correctamente con los acentos y la "ñ", que deberían ordenarse como si no estuvieran los acentos, y con `"n" < "ñ" < "o"`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ordenarlos alfabéticamente sin usar librerías externas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Si tu servidor soporta lenguaje español (lo cual seguramente es así) :

```
$palabras = array(
    'así',
    'alfabeto',
    'alfabético',
    'año',
);
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.utf8');
asort($palabras, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

var_export($palabras);
```

tendrás como salida, ordenadas las palabras por orden alfabético:

```
array ( 2 => 'alfabético',
        1 => 'alfabeto', 
        3 => 'año', 
        0 => 'así', )
```

Ver este ejemplo en acción **[aquí](http://ideone.com/7D8cKK)**!

> **SORT_LOCALE_STRING** - compara elementos como cadenas, basándose en la configuración regional en uso. Utiliza la configuración regional,
>   la cual puede cambiarse usando setlocale().

Comment: Hola Mariano, de hecho el link muestra el código resuelto, da clic en editar y pulsa el boton verde "ideone it!" para que tu mismo lo ejecutes

Comment: **Nota:** Esta respuesta resuelve la parte complicada, cuando no se cuenta con la clase Collator. Pero primero debe intentarse [la solución de ninjalj](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/479/127)... Publiqué la combinación de ambos [en mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/534/127)

Answer (score 15):

Para realizar una ordenación alfabética correcta, necesitas un algoritmo de ordenación multinivel. Dependiendo de tu instalación de PHP, puede que tengas acceso a la implementación de [UCA](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) (Algoritmo de Ordenación Alfabética de Unicode) de la librería [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/). Si no, te hará falta instalar la extensión [`php-intl`](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.intl.php).

Necesitarás un `Collator` configurado para español (`"es"`). Lo que hace este algoritmo, es separar la comparación conceptualmente en varios niveles, con distinta preferencia. Así, una diferencia en letra base es más importante que una diferencia en acentos, una diferencia en acentos es más importante que las diferencias de mayúsculas a minúsculas, ...

El objeto `Collator` es bastante configurable, puedes consultar en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/class.collator.php).

```
$palabras = array(
                'así',
                'alfabeto',
                'alfabético',
                'año',
                );

$collator = collator_create("es");
$collator->sort($palabras);
var_export($palabras);
```

Comment: Genial, funciona perfecto! Aparentemente no tengo instalada la extensión en uno de los servers que probé (`Class 'Collator' not found in...`). Podría instalarla pero voy a seguir buscando si hay alguna alternativa. Quiero que sea lo más portable posible.

Comment: @Mariano son excelentes soluciones utilizar la clase `Collator` tu provedor de servicio de hosting podría apoyarte a instalar la extensión sin root. Yo también he tenido ese problema por que normalmente no instalan la extensión o la tienen desactualizada.

Comment: Ésta es la respuesta correcta, pero acepté la respuesta que resolvió el problema que tenía... Además publiqué [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/534/127) con el código que terminé usando.

Answer (score 12):

Sólo necesitas usar la clase [`Collator`](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/class.collator.php):

> Proporciona la capacidad de comparar strings, con soporte para una ordenación apropiada, según la región.

Necesitarías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
$collator = \Collator::create('es_ES');
$collator->sort($palabras);
```

La lista se pasa por referencia, con lo que quedaría ordenada de la siguiente manera:

```
var_dump($palabras);

array(4) { 
    [0] => string(11) "alfabético" 
    [1] => string(8)  "alfabeto" 
    [2] => string(4)  "año" 
    [3] => string(4)  "así­"
}
```

Nótese que la clase `Collator` forma parte de la extensión de [Funciones de internacionalización](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/book.intl.php), que viene integrada en las versiones de PHP 5.3 y posteriores. Si estás usando una versión anterior de PHP, necesitas instalar esta extensión manualmente.

De todas formas, si quieres hacer un código lo más portable posible, siempre podrías hacer la comprobación de que la clase existe utilizando la función [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.class-exists.php), y si no, utilizar otro algoritmo más básico.

```
if (class_exists('\Collator') {
    // utiliza la clase Collator...
} else {
    // utiliza otro algoritmo...
}
```

Comment: Probado y funcionando, pero no en uno de los servers que probé (`Class 'Collator' not found in...`). Antes de instalar voy a seguir buscando alternativas para más portabilidad.

Comment: @Mariano Los problemas que vas a tener con cualquier solución que no use [el algoritmo de ordenación de Unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) son demasiados para contemplar re-implementarlo tú mismo: **por eso se inventaron las librarías.** En el caso del español, no se puede ordenar correctamente simplemente por no tener en cuenta si es mayúsculo o no o si lleva acentos o no, porque la eñe cuenta como letra entre la ene y lo o. Por ejemplo, tiene que ser *radio, ráfaga, ranúnculo, raña, rápido, rastrillo* y no *radio, ráfaga, raña, ranúnculo, rápido, rastrillo* que tendrías por defecto.

Comment: @Mariano he añadido más información sobre la clase `Collator`, que sólo está disponible por defecto a partir de la versión de PHP 5.3.

Comment: @tchrist Sin duda, no estoy tratando de reinventar la rueda. Solamente estoy tratando de garantizar que sea lo más portable posible.

Answer (score 9):

### Ésta es la solución que finalmente usé

Basándome en:

1. La [respuesta de ninjalj](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/479/127), que considero la mejor forma de ordenar alfabéticamente.
2. La [respuesta de Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/492/127), que propuso la solución cuando no se cuenta con la clase [Collator](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/class.collator.php) instalada. La parte que más me complicó, y por eso fue la respuesta aceptada.

#### Código

```php
function ordenar_alfabeticamente(&$palabras) {
    if (class_exists('\Collator')) {
        // UCA (Algoritmo de Ordenación Alfabética de Unicode)
        // Requiere la clase Collator de php-intl
        //   http://php.net/manual/es/class.collator.php

        $collator = collator_create( 'es_ES.utf8');
        return $collator->sort($palabras);
    } else {
        // Intenta setear un localismo para usar sort()

        setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.utf8', 'es_ES.UTF-8', 
                              'Spanish_Modern_Sort', 'es', 'en_US.utf8', 'en');
        return sort($palabras, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
    }
}


// EJEMPLO      =============
$prueba = array(
    'así',
    'Alfabeto',
    'alfabético',
    'Año',
);

ordenar_alfabeticamente($prueba);

var_export($prueba);
```

- Tanto `collator_create()` como `setlocale()` deberían estar fuera de la función y ejecutarse 1 vez. Están ahí para simplificar el ejemplo.

#### Resultado

```
array (
  0 => 'alfabético',
  1 => 'Alfabeto',
  2 => 'Año',
  3 => 'así',
)
```

<kbd>**[demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/GUHRSc)**</kbd>